# Can´t parse half_float

Tags: elasticsearch

I can´t understand why my data is not parsed. I got this on my logs:

> status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception",
> "reason"=>"failed to parse field [MyFIELD-NAME] of type [half_float]
> in document with id '2-17546231'. Preview of field's value:
> '73925.0'", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception",
> "reason"=>"[half_float] supports only finite values, but got
> [73925.0]"}

Note: This duplicates [[half_float] parsing error](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/half-float-parsing-error/328057)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html#_which_type_should_i_use), the maximum value for a half-float is 65504.

So 73925 is too big for a half-float, you need to pick another type.